# Expanding a table to accomodate for raneg if dates in R or Python?

Tags: python, r

I have two tables.

A High frequency Table 1

| Year | Week Number | Interest |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2006-07 | 1 | 40 |
| 2006-07 | 2 | 40 |
| 2006-07 | 3 | 40 |
| 2006-07 | 4 | 41 |
| 2006-07 | 5 | 41 |

A low frequency Table 2

| start date | end date | litres |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1- Jul-06 | 31-Jul-06 | 40,000 |
| 1 Aug -06 | 31 Jan 07 | 42,000 |
| 1 Feb 07 | 31 Jul 07 | 40,000 |

I want to join interest and litres into Table 1, so that the low frequency table expands and duplicates litres 40,000 for all weeks in the range.

How can I do this in R or Python?

I will highly appreciate your kind and expert suggestions.

I have tried the following in Python

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
low_freq_table=pd.read_csv(r"/content/low freq.csv")
low_freq_table.info()




#   Column             Non-Null Count  Dtype  
---  ------             --------------  -----  
 0   Tariff Start Date  20 non-null     object 
 1   Tariff End Date    20 non-null     object 
 2   Excise Rate        20 non-null     float64

low_freq_table['Tariff Start Date'] = pd.to_datetime(low_freq_table['Tariff Start Date'], format='%d-%b-%y')
low_freq_table['Tariff End Date'] = pd.to_datetime(low_freq_table['Tariff End Date'], format='%d-%b-%y')
expanded_table = pd.DataFrame()
for _, row in low_freq_table.iterrows():
    start_date = row['Tariff Start Date']
    end_date = row['Tariff End Date']
    Rate = row['Excise Rate']
    weeks = pd.date_range(start=start_date, end=end_date, freq='W')
    temp_table = pd.DataFrame({
        'Year': weeks.strftime('%Y-%m'),
        'Week Number': weeks.week,
        'Interest': Rate
    })
    expanded_table = expanded_table.append(temp_table, ignore_index=True)
high_freq_table=pd.read_csv(r"/content/high freq.csv")
high_freq_table.info()
```

The code works upto the expansion. But merging does not work because the week numbers repeat every year,

```
merged_table = pd.merge(high_freq_table, expanded_table, on=['Year','Week'], how='left')
print(merged_table)
```

But get the following error
*---------------------------------------------------------------------------
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
 in <cell line: 1>()
----> 1 merged_table = pd.merge(high_freq_table, expanded_table, on=['Year','Week'], how='left')
2 print(merged_table)
3 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/pandas/core/generic.py in _get_label_or_level_values(self, key, axis)
1848             )
1849         else:
-> 1850             raise KeyError(key)
1851
1852         # Check for duplicates
KeyError: 'Week'*

I will appeciate any suggestions.

Comment: Please format correctly your dates. What is the date corresponding to 2006-7, week 1?

Comment: Sorry, there are no dates. Just week 1, week 2 etc.

Answer (score 1):

I am going to make some assumptions and treat this question as being very life-like, in that it involves the processing of somewhat messy input data. We note that the date formats are inconsistent across the data so we will transform everything to date format `%Y-%m-%d` for the sake of consistency. We will also assume that the "Year" and "Week Number" columns in the high-frequency data can be used to impute a start date for the week in an intuitive way.

```r
library(lubridate)
library(stringr)

# load high-frequency data
high_freq_df <- read.csv(textConnection('Year,Week Number,Interest
2006-07,1,40
2006-07,2,40
2006-07,3,40
2006-07,4,41
2006-07,5,41'))

# clean interest column
high_freq_df$Interest <- as.numeric(high_freq_df$Interest)

# clean week number column
high_freq_df$Week.Number <- as.integer(high_freq_df$Week.Number)

# function that takes year and month (e.g. '2007-01') and week numbers and returns 
# the date representing the start of that week
to_week_start_date <- function(ym, wk) {
  d1 <- sprintf('%s-01', ym) |> as.POSIXct()
  d2 <- d1 + months(1)
  dts <- seq.POSIXt(d1, d2, by = '7 days')
  dts[ as.integer(wk) ] |> 
    as.character()
}

# tag high-frequency df with week start date
high_freq_df$start_date <- apply(high_freq_df, 1, function(x) {
  to_week_start_date(x[ 1 ], x[ 2 ])
})

# load low-frequency data
low_freq_df <- read.csv(textConnection('start date|end date|litres
1- Jul-06|31-Jul-06|40,000
1 Aug -06|31 Jan 07|42,000
1 Feb 07|31 Jul 07|40,000'), sep = '|') |>
  `colnames<-`(c('start_date', 'end_date', 'litres'))

# clean start_date column
low_freq_df$start_date <- str_replace_all(low_freq_df$start_date, '\\s+', '-') |> 
  str_replace_all('\\-+', '-') |> 
  as.POSIXct(format = '%e-%b-%y') |> 
  as.character()

# clean end_date column
low_freq_df$end_date <- str_replace_all(low_freq_df$end_date, '\\s+', '-') |> 
  str_replace_all('\\-+', '-') |> 
  as.POSIXct(format = '%e-%b-%y') |>
  as.character()

# clean litres column
low_freq_df$litres <- str_remove_all(low_freq_df$litres, ',') |> 
  as.numeric()

# combine high and low-frequency data into single data.frame
merged_df <- merge(high_freq_df, low_freq_df, by = 'start_date', all = TRUE)

# clean colnames
colnames(merged_df) <- tolower(colnames(merged_df)) |> str_replace_all('\\.', '_') 

# print result
print(merged_df)
```

```
  start_date    year week_number interest   end_date litres
1 2006-07-01 2006-07           1       40 2006-07-31  40000
2 2006-07-08 2006-07           2       40       <NA>     NA
3 2006-07-15 2006-07           3       40       <NA>     NA
4 2006-07-22 2006-07           4       41       <NA>     NA
5 2006-07-29 2006-07           5       41       <NA>     NA
6 2006-08-01    <NA>          NA       NA 2007-01-31  42000
7 2007-02-01    <NA>          NA       NA 2007-07-31  40000
```

Comment: Thank you So much. I have tried a modified code...But the error is generated because For each year, week numbers rotate from 1 to 52, based on what week that is.